Image of morphism of projective schemes
Let $\varphi:C \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of $A-$graded rings (i.e., there exists an $r\geq 1$ such that for every $d\geq 0$, we have $\varphi(C_d)\subseteq B_{rd}$). Let $I$ be the homogeneous ideal $\varphi(C_+)B$ of $B$. It is well known (for example, see [Qing Liu, Lemma 2.3.40]) $\varphi$ induces a morphism of $A-$schemes $f:\text{Proj}\;B\backslash V_+(I)\rightarrow \text{Proj}\;C$.
My question is, how to show $\overline{f(\text{Proj}\;B\backslash V_+(I))}=V_+(\text{ker}\;\varphi)$ inside $\text{Proj}\;C$? (And why $\text{ker}\;\varphi$ is a homogeneous ideal?)
